# Combine lists (n=200k) of lists and stop once shortest parent list is exhausted

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```
# list_1 : n=100k
# list_2 : n=200k
list_1 = [['name1', '001'], ['name2', '001'], ...]
list_2 = [['other1', '003'], ['other2', '005'], ...]
```

I want to combine them to the below, while stopping once either of the lists are exhausted (as per `zip()`):

```
combined_list = [['name1', '001', 'other1', '003'], ['name2', '001', 'other2', '005']]
```

I have tried `zip()` but this yields a tuple of two lists for each intended combined child list.

Is there a way to achieve this succinctly (without further looping after a `zip()`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What code have you tried? I suspect you have an issue with how you've called `zip()`.

This will add both lists together at each index, using `zip()`:

```
list_1 = [['name1', '001'], ['name2', '001']]
list_2 = [['other1', '003'], ['other2', '005']]

combined_list = [x + y for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]

print(combined_list)
```

```
[['name1', '001', 'other1', '003'], ['name2', '001', 'other2', '005']]
```

Comment: OP seemingly implies that the two lists have different length.

Comment: They rather sound like they rather just have an issue with handling the *result* of `zip`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I agree - but this will still stop once they get to the end of either list

Comment: @chemicalwill - it was my misunderstanding. You're right.

Comment: @PM77-1 no trouble at all, I had to double-check as well

Comment: Apologies, I had mistakenly thought ```zip()``` performs a full loop across the data, hence not wanting to loop again after ```zip()```. But it seems it generates each next combined pair on the fly. @chemicalwill is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Another way ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NCsIwEITv@xR7SwOl9AfBS59EQqkx0oDJhrgHffrYNlVRehqY/XZnNjx5It8dQ0zpZu88NNjj6ST86EwjShR13QhVYnbaj6NgpdtME08mbniX8dXa@MNiVVWlwDyC0bwTMcvOkZ/MN/I9qgCukRxSMHFkimhdoMioyeuRATS5s/XmMixd59BFCjeGIgMl5o83baUECNF6Lv4We8y95d5YpvQC)):

```
from operator import concat

combined_list = list(map(concat, list_1, list_2))
```

Benchmark with 1000 times longer lists ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDraoQwEIX/5ynmn3EbihcKZWGfRCRYO9ZAc2GMsNuXt4njtmVpIETnnG8yOeEWZ@/a10DbNpG3EI1FE8HY4CkCYcAhil3xAWmInu7a6N2YNPFplqhruEDXFW6wWBcKiqqqi14BV5qfSg8nqKuqYqhhyMcZ6aBapvbSgb38wcQ7TmCHoPlyWZ4FpEUYV3KQm8qkSlYV8GjH2ZQl8/vf6G0gnNEtxruHPt0VnuAGU3rrVaUP4@DLBPnQrRciO3SWaXAfKNujTS5Pqxuz8jus@udi9ucVUxbWOMmJy4wrcKt9Q7rkp6fh79ZAxkWZdzzV2JYppXWBFFaGnrXOkWvNfvaW2/YN)):

```
148 us  map_concat
192 us  list_comprehension

148 us  map_concat
192 us  list_comprehension

148 us  map_concat
193 us  list_comprehension
```

Comment: Wow. I will have to remember this one.

Comment: @chemicalwill Oddly it has become a hobby for me, who loves Python, to outsource all the hard work from Python to its C code :-) (Though list comprehension and using an operator is quite fast, I can't tell without benchmark what solution would be faster.)